# Find My Device without working Wi-Fi e.g. because it connected to public Wi-Fi that has a captive portal

Tags: wi-fi, automation, find-my-device

To my understanding, Find My Device needs to connect to the Internet to work. I know that sometimes there is the last-seen location, but this doesn't always seem to work. Sometimes my phone connects to unreliable Wi-Fi connections that may be behind a firewall, have a captive portal or simple not working because the coffee shop is overloaded etc.

Is there a way to have the phone, or specifically the Find My Device service, automatically switch to data from the SIM card if Wi-Fi is connected, but the Internet still isn't accessible? Does anyone know the details about the last-seen location, should there always be one? Are there any services or IP addresses that should be whitelisted from any firewalls or anti-trackers for Find My Device to always work?